# Getting pod logs (Kubernetes for failed pod)

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

when I get all the pods `kubectl get pod`

and I get:

```
NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS          AGE
balanced-7bbf659597-sk478             1/1     Running            0                 5d13h
hello-minikube-68ff6fd96-xxbx8        1/1     Running            0                 5d13h
mongo-express-5bf4b56f47-5s2b6        1/1     Running            8 (13h ago)       14h
mongodb-deployment-844789cd64-fjlgk   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   101 (4m30s ago)   13h
```

but then when I try to get the logs of the failed pod `kubectl logs mongodb-deployment-844789cd64-fjlgk` nothing happens, and then when I describe the pod: `kubectl describe mongodb-deployment-844789cd64-fjlgk` I get this error:

`error: the server doesn't have a resource type "mongodb-deployment-844789cd64-fjlgk"`

Comment: Have you tried the command suggested by Federico Paparoni and the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Your pod isn't available when you try see the log, you must access to the previous log file using the following command

```
kubectl logs mongodb-deployment-844789cd64-fjlgk --previous
```

Using ***previous*** parameter kubectl will dump logs for a previous instantiation of your container

Comment: Not seeing the dump. I've ran the command but nothing happened. Didn't see anything. Does it write to a particular file or something?

Comment: kubectl describe pod mongodb-deployment-844789cd64-fjlgk?